# how to split video into frames in ios and convert frames into video in server side

Tags: java, objective-c

I have a requirement to split the video into frames in objective c and send it to server.At server side , these frames should be converted into video.How can I achieve this?

Help is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to send a video on server AFNetworking library is the best way to do it.

Elsewhere if you want to convert video in to frames use this link.[iOS AVFoundation - Converting video into images at 60 fps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946534/ios-avfoundation-converting-video-into-images-at-60-fps)

Don't care about server end.In window it is possible to convert frames in to video.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can able to split video into frames with your response. But In server side, how can I convert 60 fps into video. Please suggest me. How can I implement in java?